# form_tag calling an instance of a class on the controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a `form_tag` on a Rails application that, when submitted, call an instance of a class on the controller.

**View**

```
form_tag '/order', method: :get
select_tag 'type', options_for_select(@options_for_type, @type)
text_field_tag 'numbers', nil, placeholder: "100"
submit_tag "Get Info"
```

**controller**

```
def order
  @order = Order.new(params_here).fetch_info

  @type = params[:type] || "type1"
  @options_for_type = [["type1", "type1"], ["type2", "type2"]]

  ...
end
```

This class sends some API requests (JSON).

Now problem is, I am getting an error from the API that some parameters are missing, which is expected since I haven't submitted the form with all the params, but it seems the class is called automatically when the page is loaded. I would have expected the class to be called only when the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the form_tag sort of a block? Like:

```
form_tag '/order', method: :get do
 # All form elements
end
```

Maybe displaying your route here can also help.